# IllegalStateException when using the Google Play Service Library

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, google-play-services

I'm getting an IllegalStateException when using the Google Play Service Library and I can't figure out why.

I have the `google-play-service-lib` project from the Android SDK copied to my working Git repository and imported in the workspace together with my project.

I checked in Project Proprieties->Android and the `google-play-service-lib` is added in the library section and I see a green check sign near it.

AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
            android:resource="@xml/global_tracker"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

In my `onCreate()` method from the `MainActivity.java` file the exception is thrown when `int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);` is executed.

```
     try {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        // Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            LoggerUtils.d(LOG,"Google Play services is available, create Ad");

            // Create an ad.
            adView = new AdView(this);
            adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
            adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

            // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
            // until the ad is loaded.
            FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FragmentContainer);
            layout.addView(adView);

            // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
            // get test ads on a physical device.
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
                .build();

            // Start loading the ad in the background.
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        } else {
            // Google Play services was not available, print reason
            LoggerUtils.d(LOG, "Google Play services is not available. " + String.valueOf(resultCode)); 
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LoggerUtils.e(LOG, e.getMessage());
        }
```

I LogCat I get this message and I can't figure out what the problem is

```
07-31 20:54:31.140: E/com.example.test.MainActivity.LOG(3269): The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5077000 but found 2131034114.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I checked the `google_play_services_version` in the `version.xml` from the `res->values` folder of `google-play-service-lib` project and it contains the expected number `5077000`. I can only find a reference of `2131034114` in my `proguard` folder in the `dump.txt` file. This file was created from my previous build of an apk for release where the `google_play_services_version` was part of the project but only Google Analytics was introduced not AdMob. For the tests I did, I always build a debug apk which as far as I know this is not done with proguard.

I tried cleaning the projects from the workspace several times, closing and opening again Eclipse.
I even uninstalled Google SDK, ADT and installed them again and removed `google-play-service-lib` project from workspace, delete it and copied it from the Google SDK after re-installing.

I tested on a phone running Android 4.3(Samsung stock ROM on a Galaxy S3) and Android 4.4.4(Samsung Galaxy S2 with CyanogenMod) and on both phones I get the same error.

Comment: Could it be that the build version set for `google-play-service-lib` project causes this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wohoooo! `android:resource="@xml/global_tracker"/` was causing the problem.

I don't remember what tutorial about integration of Google Analytics I found that said to add this tag, but when I had a look again over the [Overview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) of Google Analytics it didn't mention about it.

Answer (score 0):

The value of Google Play Services version is incorrect, inside `res/value/integers.xml`, change the value from:

`<integer name="google_play_services_version">2131034114</integer>`

to:

`<integer name="google_play_services_version">5077000</integer>`

The version of Google Play Services that you have is `5077000` not `2131034114`

then `Refresh -> Clean -> Build` :)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="google_play_services_version">5077000</integer>
</resources>

Comment: The above comment contains the content of version.xml from google-play-service-lib->res->values

Comment: Refresh -> Clean -> Build :)

Comment: I have no value defined for `google_play_services_version` in the `res/value/integers.xml` file from my project

Comment: By Refresh you mean to press `F5` on every project from the workspace?

Comment: yes, I see your app use Google Play Services, then add to your integers.xml  <integer name="google_play_services_version">5077000</integer>

Comment: I WANT to use Google Play Services in my project to display adds. This error appeared when I tried to integrate AdMob as you can see from the code from the question. In the meantime I added the `try catch` because my app kept crashing.

Comment: Refresh on every project -> Clean all -> Build didn't solve the problem. I will try next your suggestion to add the `google_play_services_version` in the integers.xml file from my project

Comment: `<integer name="google_play_services_version">5077000</integer>` added to my `integers.xml` file. I cleaned all projects and build them again but I get the same error.

Comment: hardcoding `5077000` in the manifest file didn't solve the problem either